# The magic of the missing 3 jobs

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

SO jobs has three types of job types:

- Permanent
- Contract
- Internship

When all are unchecked for me there are 2861 results.  When all three are checked there are 2864.  I would have thought checking all three would result in an equal count?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

When you're browsing jobs without any kind of filters, we hide the jobs you have already applied to (our assumption is that you're browsing jobs, and seeing a job you have already applied to has less value).

But when you do a search, it's possible for you to be searching for exactly the job you applied to... in that case, we're not hiding anything.

When you check the 3 types of jobs, you are applying a filter, and as that's the case, you see all the jobs :)

Comment: whatchya talkin bout willis?  Some sort of footnote would help, even if its small text on the filters.  Please note: We'll show you jobs you applied to...

Comment: when all are unchecked, you're doing an unfiltered search... then, you're seeing all the jobs you haven't applied to yet (that is, if they are not external). When you check all of them, you're doing a filtered search... then, you're seeing all the jobs, even those that you have applied through our site. Does that make sense? if it clarifies, I'll add this to the answer

Comment: I understand I just think a small footnote describing this might go a long way.  Doesnt have to be fancy..just in the fancy box you guys have at the bottom.  Note: Using filters well show you all jobs, even ones you applied for.

Comment: Then add a 4th checkbox: "include [exclude?] jobs I've applied to."

Comment: *“when all are unchecked, you're doing an unfiltered search... then, you're seeing all the jobs you haven't applied to yet”* – That is not what an “unfiltered search” is…